# How can I prevent symbol contamination between Clojure tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, clojure, tdd, leiningen

I use simulation-style tests in to ensure that my entire application works correctly. The core Clojure test library is used for tests, executed via Leiningen.  As the `-main` function runs, it defines symbols for later use within its logic. The problem is that if I accidentally use a symbol created in one `-main` test but never defined in the current `-main` test, it still has a value. I would expect to get an error that the symbol is undefined, but it seems my test environment is somehow sharing state between `deftest` executions. How can I deal with this? Move all my convenience-driven symbol definitions to a `let` statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are `def`-ing global vars inside your function, that's generally considered bad practice and reason enough to use `let` as you suggest instead.

However, you can capture a snapshot the mappings of your namespace.

```
(def ns-snapshot (ns-map *ns*))
```

So that after you intern symbols

```
(def foo 1)
(def bar 2)
```

You can determine the additions

```
(reduce dissoc (ns-map *ns*) (keys ns-snapshot))
;=> {bar #'so.core/bar, foo #'so.core/foo}
```

And un-map them

```
(doseq [[k v] (reduce dissoc (ns-map *ns*) (keys ns-snapshot))] (ns-unmap *ns* k))
```

So that you'll get the desired undefined error again

```
 foo ;=> CompilerException ... Unable to resolve symbol: foo in this context
```

Comment: Excellent information about troubleshooting the extra symbols. So one of the reasons I am `def` -ing symbols is also so that I will have logging messages before and after each symbol is defined. Should I just nest `let` statements to get this to work? Or can you think of a better way?

Comment: @user1559027 Maybe post a new question with a code example of what you are talking about? I don't understand what you are doing from that brief description.